# How to handle special characters in HTML document and JS

Tags: javascript, html, tags, special-characters

Ok, say I have checkboxes like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="name 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="name 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="name 3">
```

How can I make the following script work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checkboxlimit(document.forms.morning.class[], 2)
</script>
```

If I leave the [] within the javascript, it becomes a syntax error.
Is there a way of having those brackets in there or should that JS line be written another way?

Comment: Do you have a class array?

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use Yes? I have multiple checkboxes and only 3 can be selected. I'm then grabbing the 3 selected and emailing them off.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to:

```
checkboxlimit(document.forms.morning["class[]"], 2)
```

**Edit:**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zhgr/1/)

Comment: The brackets in javascript (and most languages) are reserved characters.  I would avoid using them for naming if possible.

Comment: this didn't seem to work, I still get a syntax error?

Comment: Using brackets for form element names is common practice when working with PHP in the backend. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays.

Comment: @ACanadianCoder: What is the error message? Personally I advice to use `document.getElementsByName('class[]')`.

Comment: Is it the same error you were seeing before?  I added my fiddle in the answer.

Comment: @FelixKling The backend is a Perl script. But if I put those brackets in the JS portion, the script doesn't work anymore

Comment: @acan: yep, but bracket notation fixes that. I'm not sure about Perl, maybe you don't need brackets in the name in that case. "Doesn't work" is not a useful error description btw.

Comment: @FelixKling lol sorry. If I do the whole     document.getElementsByName('classs[]') it doesn't give me an error anymore but the script that limits it to only 3 choices doesn't seem to work anymore. I can keep selecting more than 3 that I want. document.getElementsByName.classs would work but I need to grab the multiple values for the name="class" class.

Comment: @acan: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work, but since I don't know what the script does, there is not much I can help you with.

Comment: @FelixKling It's ok, I will try to find another way. Thanks for your input.